# Can very low engine oil cause a car to overheat going up a mountain

Tags: engine, oil, overheating

Noticed partners car overheating going up the mountain then fine. I just replaced the oil tonight as the dip stick was dry

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We really need to know, *what exactly is your question?*

Comment: Yes overheating from lack oil is wear & tear

Comment: Doesn't need to be going up a mountain. Lack of oil can make it overhead and break down anywhere.